# Bandstop filter with Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, filtering

I want to design a bandstop filter at 6.7Hz (6.2 to 7Hz). I am using the function designfilt but the filter is a passband.

```
bsFilt = designfilt('bandstopfir','FilterOrder',3, ...
         'CutoffFrequency1',6.2,'CutoffFrequency2',7, ...
         'SampleRate',256);
fvtool(bsFilt)
```

[image: bandstop filter 6.2 to 7Hz, order 3]

If I increase the order to 120 I get a bandstop filter. However, what is the effect of increasing the order?

```
 bsFilt = designfilt('bandstopfir','FilterOrder',120, ...
             'CutoffFrequency1',6.2,'CutoffFrequency2',7, ...
             'SampleRate',256);
    fvtool(bsFilt)
```

[image: bandstop filter 6.2 to 7Hz]

Is there any better way to design a filter or filter my signal from 6.2 to 7Hz? The sample rate is 256Hz.

Answer (score 1):

The higher an order of filter, the more coefficient algorithm have to fit a filter to your request. 
Downside is that high order filter is harder to implement both in hardware (where you will need more elements and it will be more suspectible to noise) and in software (where you will need more data points and it will be more suspectible to calculation error). I think there may be other downsides, i'm not expert in this area.
So with third-level filter it is just impossible to make a bandstop filter. Use any order that produce good enough results.

Comment: 120 gives me a good attenuation in the band, if I decrease the order it attenuates from 1Hz to 10Hz and then I am eliminating a lot of information in the signal. However, is 120Hz acceptable? I am not trying to implement it in hardware, I only want to filter my signal in Matlab.

Comment: 120 It's not 120Hz. It means the filter is an equation with 120 roots. So if it works for you you can use it.